# How to prevent default Behavior of mat-slide-toggle in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using mat-slide-toggle in my angular project and there is a scenario where when user toggles the mat-slide-toggle I want to first check a condition if it is true then only the toggle should be toggled to true from false and vice-versa. If condition is false, I do not want to toggle the current value of mat-slide-toggle.

HTML

```
<mat-slide-toggle [checked]="toggleValue" (change)="onToggle($event)">
```

TS

```
onToggle(event : any){
  if(!condition){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

The above approach of mine is not working. Can someone help me out in acheiving this feat.

Comment: Did you consider disabling toggle while condition is not met?

Comment: Consider Milos' suggestion above. Allowing the user to click on the toggle but not let it work is a bad user experience IMO. If you aren't going to disable it when it can't be used, you should at least notify the user why the toggle did not work when they clicked it.

Answer (score 0):

```
onToggle(event: Event) {
    if (!condition) {
      event.preventDefault();

      // Manually update the slide-toggle's checked property based on the new value of someCondition
      (event.target as any).checked = this.condition;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to pass mat-slide-toggle with a disabled condition like below :

```
<mat-slide-toggle [checked]="toggleValue" (change)="onToggle($event)" [disabled]="true">
```